# Using solar putting to run post authentication script which executes script on server

Tags: ssh, scripting, putty

I would like to use Solar Putty's ability to run post authentication scripts.
currently, I created a simple sudo script that it calls "sudo -iu flanger" which is stored in an external .sh file.

I imported the script and attached to my session so that on load it will call it.  I noticed that I had to include one line break above the sudo command inorder for it to run ...and it works.

Now, I want to create a different script that would call the same sudo but aftwards would execute a script I have on the server.  I tried the same thing in my local script by including a new line break and with the call to execute the script but it acts like it is ignoring it.

Is this even possible what I am attempting: